# How to get DB instance status via .net

Tags: c#

Is there any way to check DB instance is up or not. It is like health check monitoring. I need to connect to Database server using c# .net and should check the DB instance status and display the results.

Comment: what speaks against opening a test connection every once in a while and see if it throws an exception?

Comment: You might want to mention what kind of database server it is...

Comment: We can test the Database connection. But i want to test only Data instance status. In SQL server.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just try connecting to the DB and see if it's up or not like

```
public string GetDBStatus(string connectionString)
{
 string status = string.Empty;
try
{
  //connecting to your DB
  status = "Up";
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  status = "Down";
  //log error to somewhere
}
return status;
}
```

Comment: i don't want to check database is up or not.  only want to check the db instance..